# How to get exact measurement in WPF shapes

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently developing a simple drawing app in WPF.
One of the feature in my app is to generate image of basic geometric shapes , from the user given measurements.

so i just tried to generate square with the width/height of 96 units. So for that i should get 1 inch (*According to a device-independent unit (1/96th inch)* ). But when i print my generated image its less than 1 inch ( side lenght is 2.22 cm)

I use below code to render the image.

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((Int32)bounds.Width, (Int32)bounds.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
{
    VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(target);
    dc.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(), bounds.Size));
}

rtb.Render(dv);
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that pixels have a fixed physical representation / size. They do not.

Comment: So in order to print 1inch  squre. what would be the WPF size?

Comment: As I said, there is no direct correlation. There is no "WPF size". You have to set the right DPI/PPI when printing.

Comment: You haven't told us how you actually *print* your drawings, but you should get exact results with [`PrintDialog.PrintVisual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, saving the RenderTargetBitmap to an image file and subsequently printing that in its "natural" size should do.

Answer (score 1):

The following prints a rectangle on paper that is "exactly" 1x1 inch and positioned at 1 inch from the top left corner:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="96" Height="96" Canvas.Left="96" Canvas.Top="96"/>
</Canvas>
```

Code behind:

```
var pd = new PrintDialog();

if ((bool)pd.ShowDialog())
{
    pd.PrintVisual(canvas, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the other answers didn't just say to use 'Inches' as your units, or maybe it wasn't available back then, but that's the solution.

Here's an example to create a `Canvas` set to 8.5" x 11" to simulate a letter-sized piece of paper. It then adds three 1" squares in the top-left, top-right and bottom-right corners of the page, each with a one-inch margin from the edge of the 'paper'.

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="Paper"
    Width="8.5in" Height="11in"
    Background="White">

    <Rectangle Fill="Black"
        Width="1in" Height="1in"
        Canvas.Left="1in" Canvas.Top="1in" />

    <Rectangle Fill="Black"
        Width="1in" Height="1in"
        Canvas.Left="6.5in" Canvas.Top="1in" />

    <Rectangle Fill="Black"
        Width="1in" Height="1in"
        Canvas.Left="6.5in" Canvas.Top="9in" />

</Canvas>
```

If you then call this code, you can print it to see the results.

```cs
var printDialog = new PrintDialog();

if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
    printDialog.PrintVisual(Paper, "My First Print Job");
}
```